# Python to make a while sum up the integers of a list

Tags: python

I need help to make a function sumOfPositiveNumbers(li). A function that returns the sum of all positive integers in a list and the function should use a while loop.

Comment: This isn't very difficult.  Accumulate the values in some variable, and while you've still got elements in the list, if it's positive, add it to the accumulator.

Comment: Give it a try, post the code, and we'll help you when you get stuck.

Answer (score 5):

```
def sumOfPositiveNumbers(li):
    while True:
        return sum(i for i in li if i > 0)
```

Though I prefer the following function because instead of sum, it uses lambda expressions only

```
def sumOfPositiveNumbers(li):
   while True:
       return ((lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))
           (lambda y: f(lambda a: y(y)(a))))
           (lambda f: lambda a: len(a) and 
           (a[0] > 0) * a[0] + f(a[1:])))(li)
```

Comment: Well...that's one way to do it using a while loop...although it feels wrong from both a constraint sense and a why-don't-you-just-use-the-sum-method-directly kind of way.

Comment: maybe with this I can get the peer pressure badge

Comment: Add in a few `lambda`s and it'll be good.

Comment: Only one while loop?  Weak.  ;)

Comment: Thought about adding another case, with `urllib2` or `requests` requesting google search engine or wolfram alpha?

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple while loop like you asked:

```
def sumOfPositiveNumbers(li):
    total = 0
    index = 0
    while index < len(li):
        num = li[index]
        if num > 0:
            total += li[index]
        index += 1
    return total
```

But I must say, this job can be done a lot better like this:

```
def sumOfPositiveNumbers(li):
    return sum(x for x in li if x > 0)
```

Unless you *must* use a while-loop, using one is kinda pointless.  It really does nothing except waste more typing/time.

Comment: "*I made a very simple while loop like you asked*": why? It's not your homework assignment.

Comment: @Blender - I don't know.  I just figured I'd help him.  Besides, this might come in handy in the future for someone googling the term "python sum up positive integers in list" or something.

Comment: If someone can't write the code to add up the positive integers in a list, I'm afraid writing any sort of code for them isn't going to be helpful.